# What should i use to create web services app?

Tags: java, json, rest

As an application to get a job I need to make a web app. I'm only familiar with Java SE so here comes my concerns. I need to make web service where at the beginning there will be authentication window, then I need to show the JSON data (probably parse it and show) as table or as list with button near to choose one of the row from the table to get to the next page where there user can choose a materials and so on.

I have data in JSON on server I need to pull it from there, then I need to show data which looks like this /materialDetails?ID=x where x is ID (it's probably HTTP or URI). Should I use Java REST? If yes I need to create a site in XML and then put java data inside? There're only a few tutorials on the internet and I can't find any good(sometimes the problem is in server, sometimes with dependencies). I was looking for information also on youtube but except https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X36Dud8cS4Y I cant find anything useful? Could someone explain me this to make it at least a lil bit easier? Or just lead me to pick a specific framework. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try Spring framework web MVC. You can easily serve your data as a JSON string or even create a RestfulController.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Dynamic Web Project with Tomcat and a MySQL Database for starters. You could use RESTEasy to create a WebService that gets data from your Database.

I don't know what exactly is expected from you, but this might be a good start. "Making a web app" is a bit like saying "I need to develop a java program", it is a bit vague !

Comment: I agree that the question is very vague. It does not add much value to answer such a question.

Comment: Well we're here to help, right ? :) He has to start somewhere

Comment: A comment would be enough for this.

Comment: I know my question is a bit vague, but i don't know where to start... I know i want to make a website (but should i create it in xml?) and i need to use rest but which one is easiest to use? Jersey, Restful or RESTEasy?

Comment: I know Resteasy, it is quite straight-forward. For the webpage, a simple page with a form is enough to call a servlet !

Comment: You could start here: http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/servlet/how-to-create-a-servlet-with-eclipse-and-tomcat/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know REST but I think your application can be implemented with this technologies: HTML and Servlets/JSPs. 
I would write an authentication page in HTML (one form element with 2 inputs and a button) which would pass credentials to a Java Server Page or a Servlet (they're equivalent). There I would build the table (another HTML element) thus producing a new HTML page.

P.S.: you're using JSON as a format so there's no need to learn XML.

Comment: JSP! Are you really recommending this outdated technology?

Comment: I am still a student so I'm not familiar with any framework for developing web application. Furthermore since OP knows Java and JSPs are essentially HTML pages with snippets of Java code I thought it was a good suggestion.